# Blazor HttpContext Graph API Present challenge

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am trying to integrate Blazor server side with Microsoft Graph API.  I have Done the following

1. Registered the application for Azure AD sign via the Visual Studio new project wizard
2. Verified that the application does actually authenticate the user using Azure AD
3. Then i went and tried migrating the graph sample code from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoftgraph/aspnetcore-connect-sample/microsoft-graph-connect-sample-for-aspnet-core-21/ namely GraphAuthProvider.cs, GraphSdkHelper.cs, GraphService.cs (Code Below)

```
/* 
*  Copyright (c) Microsoft. All rights reserved. Licensed under the MIT license. 
*  See LICENSE in the source repository root for complete license information. 
*/

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MicrosoftGraphAspNetCoreConnectSample.Helpers
{
    public static class GraphService
    {
        // Load user's profile in formatted JSON.
        public static async Task<string> GetUserJson(GraphServiceClient graphClient, string email, HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            if (email == null) return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { Message = "Email address cannot be null." }, Formatting.Indented);

            try
            {
                // Load user profile.
                var user = await graphClient.Users[email].Request().GetAsync();
                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user, Formatting.Indented);
            }
            catch (ServiceException e)
            {
                switch (e.Error.Code)
                {
                    case "Request_ResourceNotFound":
                    case "ResourceNotFound":
                    case "ErrorItemNotFound":
                    case "itemNotFound":
                        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { Message = $"User '{email}' was not found." }, Formatting.Indented);
                    case "ErrorInvalidUser":
                        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { Message = $"The requested user '{email}' is invalid." }, Formatting.Indented);
                    case "AuthenticationFailure":
                        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { e.Error.Message }, Formatting.Indented);
                    case "TokenNotFound":
                        await httpContext.ChallengeAsync();
                        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { e.Error.Message }, Formatting.Indented);
                    default:
                        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { Message = "An unknown error has occurred." }, Formatting.Indented);
                }
            }
        }

        // Load user's profile picture in base64 string.
        public static async Task<string> GetPictureBase64(GraphServiceClient graphClient, string email, HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            try
            {
                // Load user's profile picture.
                var pictureStream = await GetPictureStream(graphClient, email, httpContext);

                // Copy stream to MemoryStream object so that it can be converted to byte array.
                var pictureMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                await pictureStream.CopyToAsync(pictureMemoryStream);

                // Convert stream to byte array.
                var pictureByteArray = pictureMemoryStream.ToArray();

                // Convert byte array to base64 string.
                var pictureBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(pictureByteArray);

                return "data:image/jpeg;base64," + pictureBase64;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                switch (e.Message)
                {
                    case "ResourceNotFound":
                        // If picture not found, return the default image.
                        return "data:image/svg+xml;base64,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";
                    case "EmailIsNull":
                        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { Message = "Email address cannot be null." }, Formatting.Indented);
                    default:
                        return null;
                }
            }
        }

        public static async Task<Stream> GetPictureStream(GraphServiceClient graphClient, string email, HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            if (email == null) throw new Exception("EmailIsNull");

            Stream pictureStream = null;

            try
            {
                try
                {
                    // Load user's profile picture.
                    pictureStream = await graphClient.Users[email].Photo.Content.Request().GetAsync();
                }
                catch (ServiceException e)
                {
                    if (e.Error.Code == "GetUserPhoto") // User is using MSA, we need to use beta endpoint
                    {
                        // Set Microsoft Graph endpoint to beta, to be able to get profile picture for MSAs 
                        graphClient.BaseUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta";

                        // Get profile picture from Microsoft Graph
                        pictureStream = await graphClient.Users[email].Photo.Content.Request().GetAsync();

                        // Reset Microsoft Graph endpoint to v1.0
                        graphClient.BaseUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0";
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (ServiceException e)
            {
                switch (e.Error.Code)
                {
                    case "Request_ResourceNotFound":
                    case "ResourceNotFound":
                    case "ErrorItemNotFound":
                    case "itemNotFound":
                    case "ErrorInvalidUser":
                        // If picture not found, return the default image.
                        throw new Exception("ResourceNotFound");
                    case "TokenNotFound":
                        await httpContext.ChallengeAsync();
                        return null;
                    default:
                        return null;
                }
            }

            return pictureStream;
        }
        public static async Task<Stream> GetMyPictureStream(GraphServiceClient graphClient, HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            Stream pictureStream = null;

            try
            {
                try
                {
                    // Load user's profile picture.
                    pictureStream = await graphClient.Me.Photo.Content.Request().GetAsync();
                }
                catch (ServiceException e)
                {
                    if (e.Error.Code == "GetUserPhoto") // User is using MSA, we need to use beta endpoint
                    {
                        // Set Microsoft Graph endpoint to beta, to be able to get profile picture for MSAs 
                        graphClient.BaseUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta";

                        // Get profile picture from Microsoft Graph
                        pictureStream = await graphClient.Me.Photo.Content.Request().GetAsync();

                        // Reset Microsoft Graph endpoint to v1.0
                        graphClient.BaseUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0";
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (ServiceException e)
            {
                switch (e.Error.Code)
                {
                    case "Request_ResourceNotFound":
                    case "ResourceNotFound":
                    case "ErrorItemNotFound":
                    case "itemNotFound":
                    case "ErrorInvalidUser":
                        // If picture not found, return the default image.
                        throw new Exception("ResourceNotFound");
                    case "TokenNotFound":
                        await httpContext.ChallengeAsync();
                        return null;
                    default:
                        return null;
                }
            }

            return pictureStream;
        }

        // Send an email message from the current user.
        public static async Task SendEmail(GraphServiceClient graphClient, IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment, string recipients, HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            if (recipients == null) return;

            var attachments = new MessageAttachmentsCollectionPage();

            try
            {
                // Load user's profile picture.
                var pictureStream = await GetMyPictureStream(graphClient, httpContext);

                if (pictureStream != null)
                {
                    // Copy stream to MemoryStream object so that it can be converted to byte array.
                    var pictureMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                    await pictureStream.CopyToAsync(pictureMemoryStream);

                    // Convert stream to byte array and add as attachment.
                    attachments.Add(new FileAttachment
                    {
                        ODataType = "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
                        ContentBytes = pictureMemoryStream.ToArray(),
                        ContentType = "image/png",
                        Name = "me.png"
                    });
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                switch (e.Message)
                {
                    case "ResourceNotFound":
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw;
                }
            }

            // Prepare the recipient list.
            var splitRecipientsString = recipients.Split(new[] { ";" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            var recipientList = splitRecipientsString.Select(recipient => new Recipient
            {
                EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                {
                    Address = recipient.Trim()
                }
            }).ToList();

            // Build the email message.
            var email = new Message
            {
                Body = new ItemBody
                {
                    Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath + "/email_template.html"),
                    ContentType = BodyType.Html,
                },
                Subject = "Sent from the Microsoft Graph Connect sample",
                ToRecipients = recipientList,
                Attachments = attachments
            };

            await graphClient.Me.SendMail(email, true).Request().PostAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

The above code works in the sample app even when upgrades to all latest DLLs.

When the page tries to calls the GetUserJson on the first call it states that "the headers can not be modified due to response started" or something very similar.

Does any one know how to get a auth token for graph form the blazor Azure AD sign in?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?  I'm facing the same issue and haven't found an applicable example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at BlazorGraphApi on GitHub

Blazor Server side with AD Authentication, that calls the MS Graph API on-behalf of the signed-in user using Microsoft.Idenity.Web

https://github.com/wmgdev/BlazorGraphApi